# node server localhost issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to test a simple javascript file but unable to test as on my browser the page loads for forever without any warnings and at the bottom side a text bar appears saying **"waiting for localhost..."**
On bash, I'm typing node app.js and after hitting enter terminal says **"Server Has Started"** as expected but when I go to **"http://localhost:3000"** the page keeps on **loading forever**.
I've Installed node and express rightly. (I was not able to include express here as I don't know how to.)
Please be nice, I am new to the world of development.

```js
// Express Setup

let express = require("express");
let app = express();


// Setting Up Routes

app.get("/",function(req,res) {  
    res.send = "Hi There, Welcome To My Assignement!";
});


app.get("/:actionName/pig", function(req , res){
    res.send = "The Pig Says \"Oink\" !";
});

app.get("/:actionName/dog", function(req , res){
    res.send = "The Dog Says \"Woof\" !";
});

app.get("/:actionName/cow", function(req , res){
    res.send = "The cow Says \"Moo\" !";
});


app.get("/repeat/:string/:times",function(req,res){
    let times = parseInt(app.param.times);
    for (let i = 0 ; i <= times ; i++) {
        res.send = app.param.toString;
    }
});

app.get("*" , function(req,res){
    res.send = "Error 404, Page not found!";
});


// Setting Port Up

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server Has Started!");
});
```

Comment: I think the issue is with the way you are trying to send back the response, correct me if im wrong, but I think what you want to do is something like: `res.send("content")` otherwise you are overwriting the 'send' function, and express will not return any result.

Comment: PD: Because the page was loading, we could assume the HTTP server was working. Otherwise, you would've seen an **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not override `res.send`, it is a function that you should call with values that you want to send to user.

For example your root route should look like this:

```
app.get("/", function(req,res) {  
    res.send("Hi There, Welcome To My Assignement!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to be run on browser, You will need to tell your app to listen to some specific port:

I added below snippet to the code you provided:

```
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening to requests on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Also res.send should not be assigned, instead passed the reponse to be shown

Check this REPL:

[Express App](https://repl.it/@SourabhLalwani/CookedNovelPiracy#index.js)